# How to grant access to a defined set of endpoints to an api key

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

### Background

I'm looking at using Google Cloud Endpoints to specify public endpoints on a Kubernetes cluster.

I'm able to create an API key that can access endpoints, and manually specify which endpoints can access an user.

Is there a way to have a "class" of API keys that get access to the same endpoints? Is there a better way?

### 2 use cases to support

When enabling a new client they should have access to all our public endpoints.

When adding a new public endpoint, it should be applied to all existing keys.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what are you using:

- With gRPC, [all API methods require an API key to access them](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-grpc), so, a new API key/client will have access to already existing endpoints. If you later add a new endpoint, all previous existing keys will have access to it.
- With OpenAPI, [you can restrict access to your methods](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-openapi) in a similar manner.

Comment: I'm specifically after apikey access.  I'm wondering if it's possible to have a "group" where permission changes get applied to everything in the group, or if there's another way to accomplish something similar.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to do something as you have mentioned, but what I have linked can be used in your scenario perfectly. It doesn't match it 100%, but it's the way to go.